# Copy and paste script that does not paste all the values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script to copy and paste values ​​but it does not copy the value from a formula:

```
​function onEdit() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet() 

if (sheet.getRange("Q17").isChecked() === true) { 
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet() s.getRange('F14').setFormula('= IF (O12 = 0; ""; IF (AND (L4 = 0; O4 = 0; L5 = 0); CONCATENATE ("Inventaire effectué le "; TEXT (DATE (YEAR (TODAY ()); MONTH (TODAY ()); DAY (TODAY ())); "dd mmmm yyy"); " recettes automates du jour non intégrées"); CONCATENATE ("Inventaire effectué le "; TEXT (DATE ( YEAR (TODAY ()); MONTH (TODAY ()); DAY (TODAY ())); "dd mmmm yyy"); " recettes du jour intégrées")))');

 coller ()
   } 
 } 

 function coller() {
 var p = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet() p.getRange('F5:J14').copyTo(p.getRange('F16'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
 var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("R19");   range.setValue("OK, valeurs copiées");
 var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Q17'); range.uncheck()
 var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("F14"); range.setValue(""); 
}​
```

​The result in F14 of the formula:

```
= IF (O12 = 0; ""; IF (AND (L4 = 0; O4 = 0; L5 = 0); CONCATENATE ("Inventaire effectué le "; TEXT (DATE (YEAR (TODAY ()); MONTH (TODAY ()); DAY (TODAY ())); "dd mmmm yyy"); " recettes automates du jour non intégrées"); CONCATENATE ("Inventaire effectué le "; TEXT (DATE ( YEAR (TODAY ()); MONTH (TODAY ()); DAY (TODAY ())); "dd mmmm yyy"); " recettes du jour intégrées")))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_2m2azh1FEhNgm4X8S5tY_UwOQHDA8K38Ye1YpbSZB4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your don't really need the additional function you should combine them and make better use of the event object.  Also please organize the function so that separate commands are on separate lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you set the formula in cell `F14`, add [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush).

Here I updated your code to make it easier to read and applied the flush method.

**Code:**

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet() 
  if (sheet.getRange("Q17").isChecked() === true) { 
    sheet.getRange('F14').setFormula('= IF (O12 = 0; ""; IF (AND (L4 = 0; O4 = 0; L5 = 0); CONCATENATE ("Inventaire effectué le "; TEXT (DATE (YEAR (TODAY ()); MONTH (TODAY ()); DAY (TODAY ())); "dd mmmm yyy"); " recettes automates du jour non intégrées"); CONCATENATE ("Inventaire effectué le "; TEXT (DATE ( YEAR (TODAY ()); MONTH (TODAY ()); DAY (TODAY ())); "dd mmmm yyy"); " recettes du jour intégrées")))');
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();    
    sheet.getRange('F5:J14').copyTo(sheet.getRange('F16'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("R19");   
    range.setValue("OK, valeurs copiées");
    range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Q17'); 
    range.uncheck()
    range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("F14"); 
    range.setValue(""); 
  } 
}
```

**Output:**

[image]